# Deleting a device from the Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

Yesterday I bought a new Android smartphone & performed a factory reset on my previous HTC handset. Naturally (I think) I set up my new phone under the same Google account as was registered for my HTC.

If I login to the Google Play Store, I was expecting, and maybe naively assumed to find, a way to delete the HTC handset, but I cannot seem to find a way to achieve this!

As this is only my second Android device, I have not encountered this situation before. (Perhaps there were steps I should have taken on my HTC, prior to performing the factory reset.)

I am however surprised that Google does not allow you to carry out such a basic task.

Did I miss something?

Does Google wish you to create a new account every time you change phones/tablets?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't delete it, only hide it.

1. Go to the [Google Play website](https://play.google.com/). Make sure you're logged in.
2. Click the gear icon in the upper right then click [Settings](https://play.google.com/settings).
3. Your devices should be listed there. Uncheck "Shown in menus" on the device you don't want to see any more.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for them not to allow deletion ?

Comment: Beats me. I do notice, however, that my old DROID is no longer listed under my account. Maybe because I haven't used it in over a year?

Comment: I guess there must be an expiration point. Hopefully they will add that functionality for immediate deletion in due course

Comment: It could be for the "all apps ever installed" list. As not all apps are compatible with all devices, maybe that's somehow bound to the devices the apps where used on. Just a guess.

Comment: Have things changed over the course of one year and is it in the meantime somehow possible to completely remove an old device and not only hiding it?

Comment: Seems to be a 9 month time for expiration
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=30454577&postcount=14