# Does the play store still show the provider and mobile information, if the google account is removed/changed

Tags: google-play-store

Basically what I would like to know is will the play store web version still show the provider and mobile information ie [This app is compatible with your PROVIDER_NAME DEVICE_MODEL.] if the device is factory reset/rooted/removed the google account/change google account.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Old devices stay in your list in the Play Store for quite a while after performing any of those actions. I gave one of my old Android phones a factory reset and then gave it to a relative a few months ago, they then registered it on their Play Store account, but it still showed in the list on my account for a few months afterwards (but I couldn't push apps to it from my account any more).

See also this previous question where an old device has been factory reset'd and still appears in the Play Store list: [Deleting a device from the Google Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41331/)

Answer (score 0):

None of those actions (factory reset/rooted/removed the google account/change google account) will have any effect on your provider or device information.